# Find a word and then automatically put a value in the adjacent cell

Tags: google-sheets

Using Google Spreadsheets, I need a formula automatically to enter an amount into a cell when a certain word or phrase is selected from a drop-down box (using data validation). If for example I select `GO PRO BLACK`, the cell next to it automatically should show `$529.00`. All I can see are formulae for "find and replace" or "pre-fill" and neither of those work for what I need.

How can you do that?

Comment: StackOverflow isn't really the best place to ask questions like this. Have a look at the Vlookup function https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093318

Answer (score 0):

If your validation is in A1 based on a list in E1:E3 with the required corresponding values in F1:F3 then:

```
=vlookup(A1,$E$1:$F$3,2,0)
```

in B1 should suit, assuming B1 is formatted for currency.